# Why does the GitBook code block plugin not show code on the GitBook website?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, gitbook

I am writing a GitBook. The is the legacy GitBook website and a new GitBook website.

The new GitBook website isn't showing the code that I am including via [the `include-codeblock` plugin](https://github.com/azu/gitbook-plugin-include-codeblock).

How can I get this to work?

[image]

GitBook URL: https://linrongbin16.gitbook.io/gitbook-way-to-algorithm/sort/quicksort

GitHub repo: https://github.com/linrongbin16/Way-to-Algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will work with GitBook v2. [The documentation](https://docs.gitbook.com/v2-changes/important-differences#plugins) states that

> In general, the plugin system no longer exists. However, important plugins have become first-class features in the new version.

I don't see `include-codeblock` in the list of plugins that have been integrated natively with GitBook.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, Are there any plugins alternative for include code block ?

Comment: @linrongbin, I wasn't able to find any. Inline code blocks with `\`\`\`` will work, but I don't think you can import them from other files natively. You might be able to use a pre-processor to generate files that GitBook will understand, though.

Comment: Yeah, seems the only way, Thanks so much!